# File.WriteAllText throws exception "Could not find file"

Tags: vb.net, exception, writealltext

Visual Studio 2012
VB.NET Windows forms application
.NET Framework 4.5.2

VB has finally won. I am out of ideas.

The File.WriteAllText function throws the exception "Could not find file" even though MS says that it can only throw the following exceptions ([MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.5.2)):

> ' Exceptions:
> '   T:System.**ArgumentException**:
> '     path is a zero-length string, contains only white space, or >contains one or more
> '     invalid characters as defined by >System.IO.Path.InvalidPathChars.
> '
> '   T:System.**ArgumentNullException**:
> '     path is null or contents is empty.
> '
> '   T:System.IO.**PathTooLongException**:
> '     The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system->
> defined maximum length.
> '     For example, on Windows-based platforms, paths must be less >
> than 248 characters,
> '     and file names must be less than 260 characters.
> '
> '   T:System.IO.**DirectoryNotFoundException**:
> '     The specified path is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).
> '
> '   T:System.IO.**IOException**:
> '     An I/O error occurred while opening the file.
> '
> '   T:System.**UnauthorizedAccessException**:
> '     path specified a file that is read-only.-or- This operation is not supported
> '     on the current platform.-or- path specified a directory.-or- The caller does
> '     not have the required permission.
> '
> '   T:System.**NotSupportedException**:
> '     path is in an invalid format.
> '
> '   T:System.Security.**SecurityException**:
> '     The caller does not have the required permission.

The code (it worked last week):

```
Dim filepath As String = StringFilePath + "\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM")
Dim stringFile As String = ""
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(filepath) = False Then
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(filepath)
End If

stringFile = StringHTMLHeader + StringTestDoc + StringHTMLFooter

StringLastSavedFile = Path.Combine(filepath, "Test Result " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".htm")

Try
    File.WriteAllText(StringLastSavedFile, stringFile)
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

- Checking the filepath etc. etc.
- Running as admin
- And, of course, restarting.

Comment: You can't use a slash (/) in a Windows file name. What if you dropped that from your string format?

Comment: You are right but datetime.now forces it to "-". I did change it but sadly it doesnt work.

Comment: `"Test Result " + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddHHmmss")+ ".htm"` gives me a result of `Test Result 10125731.htm`. I don't know where your hyphens are coming from.

Comment: "Test Result " + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddHHmmss")+ ".htm" also gives me a result of Test Result 10125731.htm. But i want the hyphens so i put them inbetween DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-HH-mm-ss"). With or without does not make a difference

Comment: Is the error the same? The hyphens should allow for a valid file name.

Comment: Yes exactly the same Message = "Could not find file 'C:\Users\myname\Documents\Tester\2023-10\Test Result 10-15-01-43.htm'."

Comment: Actually, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-7.0, `Could not find file` isn't one of the exceptions thrown by `WriteAllText`. Maybe it's the slash in the folder name? And the hyphen in the folder name `2023-10` doesn't exist?

Comment: Use & to concatenate strings in VB .Net. Also, is that Catch block really empty? Have you tried using StreamWriter?

Comment: @MichaelFoster That is why i am so surprised, i also found that that is not an exception. The folder is checked in a directory exist and then created. I have already written .htm files to it with the same code but somehow it doesnt work anymore since today.

Comment: 1) What happens if you comment out the Try Catch bits and leave only the File.WriteAllText part? 2) You don't need to check for My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(filepath) because it isn't a problem to call CreateDirectory if that directory already exists. 3) It would be better to use Path.Combine for the `Dim filepath...` line. 4) The string concatenation operator in VB.NET is `&`, not `+`.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b The streamwriter also does not work. I get the exact same exception. I also removed all date references so the are no hyphens anymore to make sure that that is not the problem. Still "Could not find file"

Comment: @AndrewMorton removed the try catch ->same result. Replaced all the  + for & -> same result. used path.combine -> same result

Comment: Is the concern with the specific exception type, or is it that the code shouldn't be throwing anything at all?

Comment: File operations can throw any exception, not just the ones documented.  The inevitable price of having to rely on a file system driver that can generate any failure.  Which in no small part is forever hacked by smelly software, anti-malware is on the top of that list.  Which has a reason to be concerned, by a .exe file suddenly appearing without an installer, creating a file whose content is exploitable.  Temporarily disable it and try again.

Comment: @Craig I did not expect a exception because the code worked last week and a writealltext should create the file if it doesnt exist. It became extra strange since this isnt an exception that is listed by ms as possible exception. So now i have 2 concerns 1. I want it to work 2. I dont know how since i dont know what to do with a exception that should not be there

Comment: Strictly speaking, it *is* an exception that is listed as a possible exception.  `IOException` is listed as a possible exception, and `FileNotFoundException` derives from `IOException`.

Comment: @HansPassant That was it thank you! That also explains why it suddenly stopped working

Comment: @user22716518 Seeing as anti-malware software is upset at what your program is doing, can you tell us where you are trying to write to? Somewhere like "C:\Program Files" would be expected to raise a red flag, but a location like the user's documents directory should not be likely to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and it worked.  I had to guess at some of the variables based on the various comments.

```
    Dim StringLastSavedFile As String = ""
    Dim StringFilePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Tester")

    Dim filepath As String = IO.Path.Combine(StringFilePath, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM"))
    Dim stringFile As String = ""
    If Not IO.Directory.Exists(filepath) Then
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath)
    End If

    stringFile = "TEST DATA" '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    StringLastSavedFile = IO.Path.Combine(filepath, "Test Result " & DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-HH-mm-ss") & ".htm")

    Try
        IO.File.WriteAllText(StringLastSavedFile, stringFile)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Stop
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is unnecessary:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(filepath) = False Then
```

Note this in [the documentation for the `CreateDirectory()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.createdirectory?view=net-7.0):

> If the directory already exists, no exception is thrown.

Since disk I/O is possibly the slowest thing you can do in a single computer, it's worth removing this wasteful check to call `CreateDirectory()` all the time, with no `If` conditional check first.

It's also a bad idea to wrap the file I/O in a Try/Catch that just swallows the exception. You may indeed want a try/catch, but if so put it up at a higher level, or least respond to the exception.

Additionally, the `/` character from the folder path is not valid on windows, and will create another directory level on unix systems. We also can't see the `StringFilePath` variable to know if there are other invalid characters.

Lastly, adding type info to variable names hasn't been considered good practice since at least 2004. Stop putting "String" or similar as part of the variable names (but *do* still provide a type when declaring variables), and try to declare variables to have short scopes  (ie: declare them near where they're used), so they can be collected efficiently.

Put it all together like this:

```
Dim filepath As String = IO.Path.Combine(StringFilePath, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM"))
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(filepath)

Dim fileData As String = HTMLHeader & TestDoc & HTMLFooter
Dim fullFileName = Path.Combine(filepath, "Test Result " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-HH-mm-ss") & ".htm")

File.WriteAllText(fullFileName, fileData)
```

Oh, and one more thing. Take special note of this item from the exceptions:

> System.Security.SecurityException: **The caller does not have the required permission.**

You'll need to investigate that more completely.